# Using SimpleHTTPServer to interpret failed requests and dynamically create JSON pages?

Tags: python, json, url, redirect, simplehttpserver

I have a python program that takes and validates user input ***(flightNumber,dateStamp)*** and performs three api lookups:

```
1. get flight info, 

2: find flightId, 

3: track flightID and return up to date JSON.
```

I should now like to make this information available to the web at

```
mysite.com/flightNumber/dateStamp
```

to any user passing a ***'Valid'*** flightNumber and dateTime.

Is it possible to:

Setup a SimpleHTTPServer at mysite.com and log all paths attempted.

When a connection is made to any path, it will fail as there's nothing there. (unless/until I cache)

But, I simply send a user a hold message, use 're' Python script to check if the url is ***'Valid'*** (flightNumber, dateStamp)

If not ***'Valid'***, I return an error.

If ***'Valid'*** I parse the relevant url info into parts of my existing program.

The results I get back from my existing api calls create a JSON readable page at

```
 /flightNumber/dateStamp
```

Now I forward the user to the page.

Is this possible? it seems an interesting way to achieve what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this all sounds possible, even pretty simple, especially given the lack of detail you have provided.

Comment: :) - Apologies. A smaller specific issue: how I would go about beginning to host SimpleHTTPServer and also use the same Python script simultaneously to perform an action when any URL is accessed?

Comment: IMO this should be a comment, not an answer — possibly accompanied by a question close vote.